# Cleaner formula for subtracting a set amount from a column of values each calendar day in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Formula: In cell A1 I manually type the date that I'm adding a new value, in cell B1 I have the Today() formula, and finally in cell C1 I have the formula `=YourStartingValue - (5*(B1-A1))`.

Result: The end result is that the value I input into cell C1 gets 5 subtracted from it each new calendar day. I then repeat this step in a new row for each new value that I add.

My question: is there a formula I can use so that I don't have to add the stuff in A1 and B1 each time? It'd save time and make things cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Excel automatically copies down formulas from preceding rows if the data set is assigned to [a table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c).

Comment: Is there not a singular formula I can use for this? Also, I'm using google sheets.

Comment: You can combine all into one formula = `=YourStartingValue - (5*(TODAY()-DATE(2016,1,1)))` where `DATE(2016,1,1)` is the date you have in `A1`. As far as I can tell the value in `A1` is not predictable and therefore has to be entered each time.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, that worked like a charm! One final semi-related question before I go; is there a way to auto update the cell with the current date whenever it gets edited? I found [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/_oFmvMZUCqg/CUGHlV4vV3IJ) script, but I'm not sure how to extract note info into the cell formula, or how to restrict this google script so that it only adds date-modified notes for 1 column instead of the whole sheet.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do such things in a `google-spreadsheet` (if that's possible). But maybe any of the other members here can help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have 5 subtracted from every value in some column every day, I would use a [script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) such as this one:

```
function subtractDaily() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var range = sheet.getRange('C:C');
  var values = range.getValues();
  range.setValues(values.map(function(row) {
    return [row[0] == parseFloat(row[0]) ? row[0] - 5 : row[0]];
  }));
}
```

Change the sheet name and column as needed, and set it to run daily using "Resources > Current project's triggers" dialog of the script editor.

The script checks that the cells contain numbers and does not attempt to subtract 5 from text or blank cells.

Comment: Do I have to leave my google sheets open for this to run? I'm noticing that it fails sometimes.

Comment: It should run regardless.